# Powershell Start-Process -NoNewWindow not working with -Credentials

Tags: powershell

I am looking to run an exe from powershell using a credential. I want the output to be in the same window. This is how my powershell looks.

`Start-Process` documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6

```
$username = 'user'
$password = 'password'
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
$pathNew = "c:\pathtomyexe\text.exe" 
Start-Process $pathNew -NoNewWindow -Credential ($credentials) -PassThru -Wait
```

With `-Credential ($credentials)` a new window is launched.

When I run `Start-Process` without `-Credential`, I get result in the same window as expected.

```
Start-Process $pathNew -NoNewWindow -PassThru -Wait
```

What am I doing wrong? Any pointers?

Comment: This is the behavior on my machine. I would imagine this is because your shell loads an environment specific to you. If you launched someone else's environment inside of yours, there would be conflicts with the user scope. I would suggest launching PowerShell with `Start-Process` with the credentials you specify. Then launch the .exe from there.

Comment: @AdminOfThings thanks. I will try.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer, you aren't doing anything wrong. You just won't be able to do this.

When you run `Start-Process -NoNewWindow` without `-Credential` you say: with the current already authenticated credentials, run the executable, and return the results within the same console window.

When you run `Start-Process` with `-Credential` the first question is: how do you verify that the Credentials are valid? You can't just look at the username and assume that you can re-use the existing session (e.g. the password might be wrong). To validate the credentials, `Start-Process` launches a new process as the username/password provided in the Credential object. It performs an authentication check and get a new authentication ticket.

Since it's a new process, running under a completely new context, with new authentication ticket, it ignores the `-NoNewWindow` flag as there is no way for the current console to redirect the output of the new process, and launches it as a new window.

Comment: got it. Thanks @HAL9256